# Windows Mobile 6.5 GPS Device - WaitForMultipleObjects returns 258 (timeout)

Tags: windows-mobile, gps, compact-framework

I’ve created a **GPS program that track positions in realtime in the background** for **Windows mobile 6.1** in 2008-2009. It ran fine on these devices for many years. For some reason, the same code never worked perfectly on **Windows Mobile 6.5**.

After many hour of operations (mostly when nobody use the device), I receive a “Timeout” (code 258) from the function "WaitForMultipleObjects":

```
this.GPSEvent_WaitValue = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, this.GPSEvent_Handles, 0, 45000);
```

Again, this can work for hours and suddenly, it's just impossible to get another position without :
**UPDATE:** 
 - Restarting the device (GoogleMap confirms that there's no GPS device present!)

It has something to do with Windows Mobile going to sleep and slowing up my thread.

Here's the core code (adapted from Microsoft SDK Sample):

```
/// <summary>
/// When "WindowsMobile" wake up the program to check for a new position
/// </summary>
private void OnNextGPSEvent_Callback()
{
  int SecondsToNextWakeUp = ETL.Mobile.Device.ScheduledCallback.MINIMUM_SECONDTONEXTWAKEUP;

  switch (this.SleepingState)
  {
    case SleepingStateType.SleepingForNextPosition:
      // Get position
      this.GPSEvent_WaitValue = (WaitForEventThreadResultType)WaitForMultipleObjects(2, this.GPSEvent_Handles, 0, 45000);

      switch (this.GPSEvent_WaitValue)
      {
        case WaitForEventThreadResultType.Event_LocationChanged:
          // Got a new position
          this.FireLocationChanged(this.GetCurrentPosition());

          // Manage device shutdown (save battery)
          if (this.PositionFrequency > MIN_SECONDS_FREQUENCY_FORDEVICE_SHUTDOWN)
          {
            // Close device
            this.CloseDevice();
            SecondsToNextWakeUp = (this.PositionFrequency - GPSDEVICE_LOAD_SECONDS_LOAD_TIME);
            this.SleepingState = SleepingStateType.SleepingBeforeDeviceWakeUp;
          }
          else
          {
            // Default Wait Time
            this.SleepingState = SleepingStateType.SleepingForNextPosition;
          }

          break;

        case WaitForEventThreadResultType.Event_StateChanged:
          break;

        case WaitForEventThreadResultType.Timeout:
        case WaitForEventThreadResultType.Failed:
        case WaitForEventThreadResultType.Stop:
          // >>>>>>>>>>>>>> This is where the error happens <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
          // >>>>>>>>>>>>>> This is where the error happens <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
          // >>>>>>>>>>>>>> This is where the error happens <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

          // Too many errors
          this.ConsecutiveErrorReadingDevice++;
          if (this.ConsecutiveErrorReadingDevice > MAX_ERRORREADINGDEVICE)
          {
            this.CloseDevice();

            SecondsToNextWakeUp = (this.PositionFrequency - GPSDEVICE_LOAD_SECONDS_LOAD_TIME);
            this.SleepingState = SleepingStateType.SleepingBeforeDeviceWakeUp;
          }
          else
          {
            // Default Wait Time
            this.SleepingState = SleepingStateType.SleepingForNextPosition;
          }

          break;
      }
      #endregion
      break;

    case SleepingStateType.SleepingBeforeDeviceWakeUp:
      this.OpenDevice();

      SecondsToNextWakeUp = GPSDEVICE_LOAD_SECONDS_LOAD_TIME;
      this.SleepingState = SleepingStateType.SleepingForNextPosition;
      break;
  }

  if (this.IsListeningGPSEvent)
  {
    // Ajustement du prochain rappel
    this.NextGPSEvent_Callback.SecondToNextWakeUp = SecondsToNextWakeUp;
    this.NextGPSEvent_Callback.RequestWakeUpCallback();
  }
}
/// <summary>
///Create Thread
/// </summary>
private void StartListeningThreadForGPSEvent()
{
  // We only want to create the thread if we don't have one created already and we have opened the gps device
  if (this._GPSEventThread == null)
  {
    // Create and start thread to listen for GPS events
    this._GPSEventThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(this.ListeningThreadForGPSEvent));
    this._GPSEventThread.Start();
  }
}
private void ListeningThreadForGPSEvent()
{
  this.GPSEvent_WaitValue = WaitForEventThreadResultType.Stop;
  this.IsListeningGPSEvent = true;

  // Allocate handles worth of memory to pass to WaitForMultipleObjects
  this.GPSEvent_Handles = Helpers.LocalAlloc(12);
  Marshal.WriteInt32(this.GPSEvent_Handles, 0, this._StopHandle.ToInt32());
  Marshal.WriteInt32(this.GPSEvent_Handles, 4, this._NewLocationHandle.ToInt32());
  Marshal.WriteInt32(this.GPSEvent_Handles, 8, this._GPSDeviceStateChanged.ToInt32());

  this.Start_NextGPSEvent_Timer(this.PositionFrequency);
  this.SleepingState = SleepingStateType.SleepingBeforeDeviceWakeUp;
  this.OnNextGPSEvent_Callback();
}
```

Comment: I've reproduced the problem this morning (it's not that easy). I though Google Maps was able to reset the GPSID but it's not true. I've tried killing my program but nothing works. It's seems there's only one option: restart ! How can I crash the GPS for the whole device like that ??

Comment: I found some application done by the community to reset the GPS device. That didn't do anything. I'll be checking next to programmatically reset the GPSID service myself.

Comment: Just wrote a small program that reset the GPSID service. It did not work either. Not enough place for the code but here's a bit:       IntPtr hGPS = CreateFile("GPD0:", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, IntPtr.Zero);
      if (hGPS.ToInt32() != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
      {
        int Out = 0;
        UInt32 DeviceIOValue = DeviceIoControl(hGPS, ioctlCode, null, 0, null, 0, ref Out, IntPtr.Zero);

        CloseHandle(hGPS)
      }

Answer (score 0):

Does the C# GPS sample included with the Windows Mobile 5/6 SDK have the same issue? If it does, then this is likely a driver issue and you will need to take it up with your hardware manufacturer or OEM.

You can mitigate this issue by polling the GPS driver rather than relying on the position changed callbacks of the intermediate driver interface.

There is no standard method of resetting the GPS hardware. The GPS is 'on' when a program is using it and 'off' (or in a very low power mode) when no program is using it. If your GPS is on the WWAN chip, you may be able to reset it by turning off and on the WWAN modem. Alternatively, some GPS chips accept ASCII or binary serial commands to reset the GPS itself, but these are chipset specific. You will need check with your GPS chipset manufacturer for these codes.

Your GPSID reset code, which I assume is from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202088.aspx), is the same as forcing all GPSID clients to disconnect which puts the GPS in a low power state, but may not actually reset the hardware.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply. The code you see in this post is based on the SDK. It has been augmented only to stay alive when the device is put to sleep. So I guess your right, this is a driver issue. 

Since this same code works on any InterMec (winMo 6.1) device and not on Motorola (winMo 6.5.3), it's either this or the Windows Mobile version.

Since WinMo has no more future anymore and this unsolvable issue, I cancelled the project.